# Add JSON Responses to Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, afnetworking

The endpoint JSON response is always just one `array`, with two `dictionary` items.

```
[
    {
        "item_1": "Austin",
        "item_2": "Texas"
    }
]
```

I need to make an **`item_1` and `item_2` array, that are able to add items to them every time a new call is made** to the endpoint.  Have any ideas of the best way to set this up?

Right now, I'm adding a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *item1Array;
```

Then setting that `item1Array` property equal to the response from the JSON endpoint:

```
self.item1Array = response;
NSLog(@"Response Array: %@", self.item1Array);
```

Logging it:

```
2016-04-01 13:35:42.787 A[66185:7391524] Response Array: (
        {
        "item_1" = Austin;
        "item_2" = Texas;
    }
)
```

But getting stuck when trying to add the new responses to the `item1Array` and `item2Array`.

Ultimately, I'd like the `item1Array` to have multiple items in it that reflect the items that were retrieved with the query to the endpoint (i.e. `[@"Austin", @"Denver"]`).

Any help or different ways of thinking about this than what I'm doing would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to make different arrays for item1 and item 2?

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Yes, one array for the cities (item1), and one array for the states (item2)

Comment: Then you need to have two NSMutable arrays and parse the JSON and append item1 to first mutable array and item2 to second mutable array

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari So just taking `item_1` for example: I've got a `NSMutableArray` called `item1Array` already right? I believe I also have the JSON parsed with `response`? So where I'm stuck is the appending of `item_1` into `item1Array`, any ideas?

Comment: Basically you are overwriting the mutable array, You should take a temp json array or responseArray. Then you also have a dictionary inside array. You  need to use value for key to fetch specific key values like item_1 and then append it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your two NSMutable arrays. According to your json we have only 1 object for array and in that object there is a dictionary with 2 keys and values.

Firstly initialize your Mutable arrays somewhere in `viewDidLoad`

```
item1Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
item2Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then append whenever you get response.

```
//Appending item_1 in item1Array which is a NSMutableArray
[item1Array addObject:[[responseArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"item_1"]];

//Appending item_2 in item2Array which is a NSMutableArray
[item2Array addObject:[[responseArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"item_2"]];
```

Comment: When I do `[self.item1Array addObject:[[self.item1Array objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"item_1"]];` or `[self.item1Array addObject:[[response objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"item_1"]];` I get null though.  I'm definitely getting a response array, but whatever appending I'm doing doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: I have edited the answer, you must initialize the mutable arrays first also. And take some different array for json response. Not the same array

Answer (score 0):

So your 2 arrays should already exist when the JSON is parsed, so you can just append new contents. You can extract the contents you want using KVC:

```
NSArray *items = [response valueForKey:@"item_1"];
```

And then you just need to append the `items`.

Comment: So if I add `@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *w1Array;` as a mutable array that will hold all of the cities that get appended over time, then do `[self.w1Array addObject:items];` or `[self.w1Array addObjectsFromArray:items];` I get `null`.  Is that how I'm supposed to be appending?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Wain I wish I had enough cred to up vote you, you were helpful to me

Comment: Not `addObject:`, because `items` is an array. `addObjectsFromArray:`.